# mysql (AWS) connection fails when connecting to the mysqldeveloper using end point

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

i have created `mysql instance` in the `AWS` and itried to connect with mysql developer using `end point` provided by AWS.

when i test my connection in the mysql developer it gives following `ERROR`

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

is it the problem of AWS Mysql instance or of mysql connection driver?

please help me i have got stuck here for two days.

**by changing security group source to anywhere my problem got solved**
when i create table the following error is coming.

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE employee 
( id number(5), 
name char(20), 
dept char(10), 
age number(2), 
salary number(10), 
location char(10) 
)
Error report -
SQL Error: No database selected
```

Comment: I guess in firewall you will have to allow port 3305 if you want to connect to a remote host

Comment: okay let me check with it.

Comment: nope sir it did not work, yesterday once the connection had established , but i deleted that connection , and tried with new connection, then this problem is araising

Comment: @raj you are trying to connect over the internet right? Is it a EC2 hosted MySql instance or the RDS one. Give more explanation about the question. Why i am asking is need to verify whether you have configured your AWS infrastructure correctly.

Comment: @raj what query string are you using to test this - When it was working yesterday where you on a VPN or different internet connection?

Comment: @vaisakh it is RDS

Comment: @jarnohenneman i am using the end point to configure **example.cn89qwuvudeu.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com**

Comment: @raj so I think the connection is over the internet. So have you checked the RDS configuration `Is Publicly Accessible` field value as `YES`, and also please check whether the port `3306` is opened to map to your source ip address in `SecurityGroup` configuration.

Comment: publicly accessible is kept yes and how to check  that  3306 is opened

Comment: security group config is  **MYSQL/Aurora   
  TCP
  3306
  sg-df7b3ab7 (default)**

Comment: yes got it i changed source to any where .its done

Comment: but  new problem i faced place check my question i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

just append database name for your table like `create tablemydb_name.sampletable(name varchar(50));`

```
it will resolve n o database select error
```

And for `AWS mysql` instance change security group source to any where in **inbound rules**